# How to copy Jenkins config files in a jenkins pipeline to Web server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, configuration-files

I have some files.properties in Jenkins config File that I need to copy to a server during the jenkins pipeline.

pipeline code is more a less as showed, just to get an idea.
How can I add a step that copy this config file from jenkins on a destination server after las step after step DEPLOY WAR TO SERVER in pipeline like for example : "sh Scp file.properties jenkins@destinationserver:/destination/path/file.properties"

[image]

```
code {
stage ('Code Checkout') {
            git branch: 'master',
                credentialsId: 'b346fbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                url: 'https://xxxxxxx@bitbucket.org/gr/code.git'

        }
stage ('Check Branch') { 
        sh 'git branch'
}

stage('Compile and Build WAR') {
        sh 'mvn clean compile war:war'

stage ('Deploy WAR to server') {
            sh "scp .war jenkins@serverIp:/var/lib/tomcat/.war"

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite easy. You need to install the [Config File Provider Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin) and then you can generate the appropriate line by visiting `htts://localhost/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/`. From there in the dropdown you can choose `configFileProvider` and fill the rest of the form.

The end result will be something like this:

```
configFileProvider(
    [configFile(fileId: 'maven-settings-or-a-UUID-to-your-config-file', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
    sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS clean package'
}
```

Comment: that is for mvn, in this case I´m using a regular "file.properties" as showed on image that I want to copy to a remote server during the pipeline. chek last image I uploeaded.

Comment: It is still the same. With the example above you are copying the `fileId` on the slave and setting the path of the file as the environmental variables `MAVEN_SETTINGS`. Then, in the `sh` step the env var is being used to specify where the copied mvn settings.xml file is.  In your case you would just change the variable name to something else and set the proper `fileId` to point to the `.properties` file you have.

Comment: ok so at the end it would be something like  
{sh cp $CONFIG_FILE_PATH resources/config.properties'
 sh scp resources/config.properties jenkins@server:/path/to/copy/config.properties  ?...}

Comment: Yes, you could do something like that indeed. If you'd like - you can test it in your pipeline by doing `sh "cat $CONFIG_FILE_PATH"` and it will output the entire file in your build log. So, you can `sh "scp $CONFIG_FILE_PATH user@remote:/path/file"` it as well.